# Having trouble connecting button in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Creating the form fields/labels in Xcode. Having issues with submitting the form.

I setup the JSON/JSON Response codes just not sure how to link up the submit button to process these POST fields.

Tried to link the button using an action but unable to do so. See screenshot.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5Q4Wn5z.png]

Comment: Did you try control + drag? Is the "custom class" field, the same class as your `UITableViewController` subclass?

Comment: Yes I did try a ctrl+drag. The classes I am using are UITableView and UIButton

Comment: Yes, but simply dragging a TableviewController into interface builder will not connect these 2 files. You must use the right hand inspector, 3rd tab from the left, and enter your custom class name

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2yY4L is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: close, instead of "submit", input your `UITableViewController` subclass name.